How to implement refresh token logic in android using kotlin
I am new to oauth2.0. I am trying to refresh my token silently on or before it expires so the user can continue using my service. I have a function for authorization, getting pkce authorization code and getting the refresh token. My issue is how to implement all these functions so as to enable me to refresh the token silently (without the user knowing and without interrupting the user). I would really appreciate it if anyone could assist me with this. TIA
My current logic is to store the refresh token, the access token, and the authorization code in the data store. What I do is onStart, I check if the authorization code is empty if it is true it performs the authorization function then it always performs the getting pkce authorization code function. I am sure there is a better way to do this.
